# Sending large file as data inside JSON via cURL

Tags: bash, curl

I'm trying to send a file as base64-encoded data via POST to the Bugzilla REST API as follows:

```
curl -X POST https://www.example.com/rest/bug/$id/attachment -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d "{\
\"login\" : \"$username\", \
\"password\" : \"$password\", \
\"ids\" : [ $id ], \
\"summary\" : \"...\", \
\"content_type\" : \"application/gzip\", \
\"data\" : \"$data\"\
}"
```

What I'm getting is an error from cURL that the argument list is too long. Presumably, this is because the file (`$data`) I'm trying to send is more than the shell maximum (the file is 11M). What I've seen online is that the best way to get around that is to have cURL read the data from a file using `--data-binary`. But since I need to send a username and password, I'd prefer not to have to save the entire file with them inside.

Is there some way to get around this maximum, or is there another way to send a large amount of data this way? I prefer native Linux tools, as I want this script to be portable.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a file like this, which is the recommended way.

```
curl -i \
    -H 'Accept:application/json' \
    -H 'Authorization:Basic $username:$password' \
    -X POST -d @datafile.txt https://www.example.com/rest/bug/$id/attachment
```

Comment: I didn't think Bugzilla supported an authorization head, and it looks like it doesn't. When I tried to use it I got back `{"documentation":"https://www.example.com/docs/en/html/api/index.html","error":true,"code":410,"message":"You must log in before using this part of ...."}`. There isn't a 410 error in the Bugzilla documentation, and there are errors for when the authorization is invalid instead of just not present.